# mozilla firefox dropdown hide option issue for key up and key down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multi select dropdown, having search box. when user search any character, I display matching option value in that select box.
but when i click on that select box, Using key up and key down arrow key i navigate, then in firefox it is navigating through hidden element also.
which work fine on chrome and IE.
Problem is that, in firefox if we hide option of select box, then up key and down key, navigate from that hidden option also.
Could any budy please help me in such a seniro

[image]

Comment: Please provide some code so we can help you

Comment: I take reference from [link](https://github.com/crlcu/multiselect). could you please visit that link